# VSC how to exclude node_modules/ from # symbols lookup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code (Windows 11, version 1.74.3) mainly for TypeScript. I have excluded `node_modules` from searches in `files.exclude` and `search.exclude`. Indeed, with a `Ctrl-Shift-F` I don't see anything from `node_modules`. Perfect.

But if in the command palette I enter, for example, `#error` I see also all error symbols from packages. This could be useful sometimes, but clutter the resulting list of symbols. Is there a way to have `#` excludes `node_modules`?

Thanks for clarifying!
mario

Comment: it's a (ridiculously long) open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46718

Comment: Seems that till the issue is solved, I have to live with this behavior